# send DM in discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

code:

```
if(command === "dm"){
    console.log((chalk.yellow)`You ran a command: dm`)
    const id = args[0]
    const message = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    let user = client.users.cache.get(id)
    user.send(message)
}
```

error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

whats the problem? ive been using this exact same code but with channels which does work. btw the command looks like this: -dm userIDhere messagehere

Comment: Try to `console.log(args[0])` and make sure it is a valid user id.

Comment: 1)`args[0]` is not a valid user id or 2) The user is not in cache and needs to be fetched.

Comment: alright it was the fetch thing, just fixed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

`client.users.cache.get(id).send(message);`
will work

so it will look like:

```
    console.log((chalk.yellow)`You ran a command: dm`);
    const id = args[0];
    const message = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    client.users.cache.get(id).send(message)
};
```

Comment: What do you think the difference is between `\`${id)\`` and `id`. If `id` is a string (and it is), `\`${id}\` === id`.

Comment: Apologies, brain was kinda fried night and hadn't realized.